# meaning of the word "Reel"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I searched the meaning of **reel** in a couple of dictionaries and 
 got the meaning as

> to walk, moving from side to side, looking like one is going to fall.

but still I am not able to understand it. What does it mean? Can I have an example in favor of that word?

Comment: Wiktionary has a good entry http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reel

Comment: Try a learner's dictionary for examples, like [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/reel_2) or [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/reel_1?q=reel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Psalm 127:27

> They reel to and fro, and stagger like a drunken man.

The definitions you found describe how someone who is drunk might walk: not in a straight line, and in danger of falling over.

Answer (score 0):

To reel in terms of walking is not commonly used (Andrew Leach's example is a good one though).  What you would more often see:  'He reeled backwards from the punch' or 'The news sent him reeling' -- meaning that he appeared unsteady, as though he was about to fall over.

Answer (score 0):

A reel is a type of dance. In the Highland Reel (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_highland_dance), the dancers weave side to side and around each other in a way that the definition you provide suggests. Perhaps it comes from the dance, then?

Comment: I should add that it is danced very quickly, giving the impression of instability.

Comment: Or the dance from the word?